# Alternative to SMS phone number verification - worldwide

Tags: android, ios, sms

I have been trying to find a way around validating a phone number (Android and iPhone) without using the SMS verification system. The reason is purely around cost. I would like a FREE solution.

Can I safely assume that Android OS will provide me with the user's phone number (no need for verification), making it a free solution?
How about iOS?

Thanks all for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Android allows you to get the phone number. Your app will need the `READ_PHONE_STATE` permission from the user.

Then it's simple to get the phone number like so:

```
TelephonyManager tMgr =(TelephonyManager)mAppContext.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
mPhoneNumber = tMgr.getLine1Number();
```

ios does not allow you to get the user's phone number. They consider it a security risk.

one developer who tried this received a response from apple that said:

> "For security reasons, iPhone OS restricts an application (including its preferences and data) to a unique location in the file system. This restriction is part of the security feature known as the application's "sandbox." The sandbox is a set of fine-grained controls limiting an application's access to files, preferences, network resources, hardware, and so on."
>
> The device's phone number is not available within your application's container. You will need to revise your application to read only within your directory container and resubmit your binary to iTunes Connect in order for your application to be reconsidered for the App Store.

So, you will still probably need to use the SMS service. Good luck!

Comment: I just found out that the TelephonyManager is picking up the phone number stored on the SIM card. However, this method is not reliable as not all mobile phone carriers will store the phone number on the SIM as it is not compulsory to do so.

Comment: Agreed. hence I said you will probably need to use SMS service for better verification.

Comment: It's reported in thousands of answers and comments that `getLine1Number()` returns nothing most of times, as in most cases the number is not stored on the SIM, plus one can configure it's own number with a fake one. You commented that it's probably needed to use SMS anyway because of, in your own words, Apple's restriction, but the fact is that the 1st part of your answer is totally wrong.